# Adding Vector Class Definition

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a vector class in python and cannot seem to figure out the logic for this addition function. The code below includes examples.

Note: Vec() is a class with two member variables. v.D which sets the domain of the vector and v.f which is a dictionary mapping the domain to respective values. Also note that elements in v.D that are mapped to 0 are **assumed** to be in v.f.

```
def add(u,v):
    """
    Returns the sum of the two vectors.
    Make sure to add together values for all keys from u.f and v.f even if
    some keys in u.f do not exist in v.f (or vice versa)

    >>> a = Vec({'a','e','i','o','u'}, {'a':0,'e':1,'i':2})
    >>> b = Vec({'a','e','i','o','u'}, {'o':4,'u':7})
    >>> c = Vec({'a','e','i','o','u'}, {'a':0,'e':1,'i':2,'o':4,'u':7})
    >>> a + b == c
    True
    >>> a == Vec({'a','e','i','o','u'}, {'a':0,'e':1,'i':2})
    True
    >>> b == Vec({'a','e','i','o','u'}, {'o':4,'u':7})
    True
    >>> d = Vec({'x','y','z'}, {'x':2,'y':1})
    >>> e = Vec({'x','y','z'}, {'z':4,'y':-1})
    >>> f = Vec({'x','y','z'}, {'x':2,'y':0,'z':4})
    >>> d + e == f
    True
    >>> b + Vec({'a','e','i','o','u'}, {}) == b
    True
    """
    assert u.D == v.D

    return Vec({v.D}, {x: v.f.get(x, 0) + u.f.get(x, 0) for x in v.D})
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: When I try to submit I get an 'unhashable type: set; error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My wild guess is that v.D is a dictionary, so this

```
{v.D}
```

will be equivalent to

```
{{...}}
```

which is not the desired.

Comment: Oh lordy, thank you Christian! I can't believe I did not see that. Such a stupid mistake...+1

Comment: Looks like ```v.D``` is a set, which is mutable.